# Struts Action Context different after Struts upgrade

Tags: java, struts2

I updated my Struts library to 2.2.1 and had to make a few minor adjustments, but the more testing I do the more I'm seeing problems.

We normally use:

```
actionName = ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation().getProxy().getActionName();
```

to return the action name, so if I'm requesting /home.do it works, but if I need to run something on home, like /home!save.do my normal flow use to be to return the above and normally that would give me just home and I would add the .do. Now it returns the whole thing, and results in a loop, or in some cases a fail form submit.

For example

```
/manageUsers!editUser.do

<form action="${actionName}!save.do"> --- IN JSP
```

Shows up in the browser as:

```
<form action="/manageUsers!editUser!save.do">
```

The `actionName` use to just return "manageUsers" now for some reason I'm getting the `actionName` and the method name all together.

Comment: Why have you upgraded to 2.2.1 instead of the latest 2.3.16.x ? Why are you using JSP EL instead of Struts Tags, since you are using Struts ? :| Unless it is a 8 hours patch on a legacy app, please consider migrating both your libraries and metodologies to the 2014's state of the art

Comment: DMI is disabled by default so Struts treats `manageUsers!editUser` as an action name, not action and method.

Comment: DMI was already set to false but thank you because that did seem like a possible problem.

Comment: @user2282811 In your version it's not disabled, but if you upgrade to the latest version it was already.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get action name from the context itself

```
actionName = ActionContext.getContext().getName();
```

or from the action mapping

```
actionName = ServletActionContext.getActionMapping().getName();
```